# Add new filed on Portal(portal module) Website odoo13

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I want to add a new field called about_me to the portal module but when I click the confirm button, an "Unknown field" error appears, could there be something missing in the inhertit template method?

[This error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofLQO.png)

[Python code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I73Em.png)

[xml code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cc9XG.png)

Comment: Did you try to override the controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The controller will check if the fields present in `post` are also present in `MANDATORY_BILLING_FIELDS` or in `OPTIONAL_BILLING_FIELDS`

```
@route(['/my/account'], type='http', auth='user', website=True)
def account(self, redirect=None, **post):
    ...
    if post and request.httprequest.method == 'POST':
        error, error_message = self.details_form_validate(post)
```

The part of `details_form_validate` that will return the error message:

```
def details_form_validate(self, data):
    ...
    unknown = [k for k in data if k not in self.MANDATORY_BILLING_FIELDS + self.OPTIONAL_BILLING_FIELDS]
    if unknown:
        error['common'] = 'Unknown field'
        error_message.append("Unknown field '%s'" % ','.join(unknown))

    return error, error_message
```

After that, it will check if there is no error to write values and redirect you to `/my/home` or the one defined by the `redirect` parameter.

To avoid this issue just add your field to `OPTIONAL_BILLING_FIELDS` :

```
from odoo.addons.portal.controllers.portal import CustomerPortal

CustomerPortal.OPTIONAL_BILLING_FIELDS.append('about_me')
```